# How to detect android physical device from eclipse?

Tags: android, usb

I'm having latest android adt bundle contains Android SDK,Eclipse and ADT. I have created the app from this bundle, then I want to run the app from eclipse to real device(My Android Phone).  I'm not able to connect the device from eclipse.

So, I followed this URL for finding the device,

http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/oem-usb.html

Now I'm not able to see the the USB driver path(The Google USB Driver is located in `<sdk>\extras\google\usb_driver\.`)

How can I solve this?

Comment: Have you installed the drivers of your device?

Comment: which device are you referring?

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: Is Your real device detected by your OS?

Comment: yes. I have installed the driver

Comment: My device is HTC. I'm able to detect from my OS.

Comment: Have you checked the developers option for debugging in settings of android device OS.

Comment: if you are installed the correct device driver for your mobile it show automatically in DDMS Devices list

Comment: If your issue is resolved, accept the answer that was correct or just put an answer and accept it, so that, it helps developer looking for correct answers.

Answer (score 1):

Turn on USB Debugging in your phone settings

Comment: @AdisAksh: Which OS are you using onyour PC ?

Answer (score 1):

Follow this approach-

check if usb debugging is checked or not.then

Go to computer->rightclick->manage->Device manager->Android Device-> Right Click->Update driver software->Browse my computer for driver software->let me pick from a list of device-> and choose android Composite ADB interface and Click Next to upgrade the driver.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install proper driver of your device. Only then your Eclipse can detect your device to launch you application on it.

**How can I install the driver and how can I be sure it is installed?**

1. Go to Computer(right click) -> Manage ->  Device Manager.
2. If your device is categorized in "other devices" or "portable
   devices" something is not right. Double click on the device listed
   in Device manager. Inside it check your driver details.
3. If there are no driver details shown or the button is not clickable then the driver is not installed. If it is you need to update it.
4. Windows should automatically do this for you. If not you can click on the icon when it is searching for the device driver and select "install most suitable driver automatically".
5. Either case mentioned in point 3 the end result should be that after installing your driver(mind any suitable driver if your device driver is not available). Your device should be listed under the category "Android USB Devices"
6. Now you can be sure that ADT would detect your device.

PS : I have mentioned any suitable driver because in my case I had Micromax A69(ICS) and it installed HTC driver. After this Android ADT started detecting my device. I am using Windows 7. Attaching a screen shot just for the reference -

[image]

Answer (score 0):

this command `adb devices` can show you physical devices connected to your computer. Search adb inside ADT bundle